# curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: centos6, https, curl

I've a CentOS6 vps on which O trying to access https url through curl it gives not supported error

```
# curl https://google.com
```

curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is the OpenSSL library installed?

Comment: yes # which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl

Comment: Output of `curl --version` please.

Comment: potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884669/curl-1-protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl

Comment: @Brian there are two version of curl installed one at /usr/bin/curl 7.19.7 and other at /usr/local/bin/curl 7.46.0

Comment: The output of `curl --version` includes more than just the version.

Comment: @Brian  `usr/bin/curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz`  This version supports ssl but its not supporting HTTPS using TLS 1.2, which i'm trying to connect.

Comment: Tested their site with https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh and Qualys.  There is something strange going on.  Qualys shows them supporting **all** protocols, whereas the bash+openssl testssl.sh is choking on negotiation.  Google is probably testing something.  Anyway, if you do ldd /usr/bin/curl you can see which openssl libraries curl is compiled against.  Most versions of curl on redhat will only support up to TLS 1.0.  You may want to test against a different site.